# Incrementing values in 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm attempting to increment the values in a 2d array for a game I'm making, but I'm getting the same value in each array instead.  This is the code:

```
def matrix(grid):

    nrows = len(grid)
    ncols = len(grid[0])

    for i in range(nrows):
        for j in range(ncols):
            grid[i][j] += 10

    for row in grid:
        print(row)

rows = 4
cols = 4
grid = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
matrix(grid)
```

The output is:

```
[10, 10, 10, 10]
[10, 10, 10, 10]
[10, 10, 10, 10]
[10, 10, 10, 10]
```

Where as I would like it to be

```
[10, 20, 30, 40]
[10, 20, 30, 40]
[10, 20, 30, 40]
[10, 20, 30, 40]
```

Also, is it possible to stagger and use two nested for loops to provide incremented values for each row?  Such as:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40]
[20, 40, 60, 80]
[10, 20, 30, 40]
[20, 40, 60, 80]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this loop:

```
for i in range(nrows):
    for j in range(ncols):
        if (i % 2 != 0):
            grid[i][j] += 20*(j+1)
        else:
            grid[i][j] += 10*(j+1)
```

for the output:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40]
[20, 40, 60, 80]
[10, 20, 30, 40]
[20, 40, 60, 80]
```

Comment: Interesting, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

The output is as expected: the following line of code adds 10 to each cell, and since each is zero on entry, it becomes 10 in output

```
for i in range(nrows):
    for j in range(ncols):
        grid[i][j] += 10
```

Maybe the following would do, depending on what you are trying to do

```
for i in range(nrows):
    for j in range(ncols):
        grid[i][j] += 10*(j+1)
```

And for the two-loop version (not the output you give, but I didn't find the pattern)

```
for i in range(nrows):
    for j in range(ncols):
        grid[i][j] += 10*(i+j+1)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have to modify the whole list, try to do this with comprehensions. It is efficient. So, your problem can be solved with [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this

```
rows = 4
cols = 4
grid = [[0] * cols for _ in range(rows)]
print [[(i * 10) for i in xrange(1, len(row) + 1)] for row in grid]
```

**Output**

```
[[10, 20, 30, 40], [10, 20, 30, 40], [10, 20, 30, 40], [10, 20, 30, 40]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code to:

```
for i in range(nrows):
    val = 10
    for j in range(ncols):            
        grid[i][j] = val
        val += 10
```

Comment: Or simply `grid[i][j] = 10*(j+1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def matrix(grid):

nrows = len(grid)
ncols = len(grid[0])
grid[0][0]=10;
for i in range(nrows):
    for j in range(ncols):
if(j!=0)
      grid[i][j] = grid[i][j-1]+10;
else 
grid[i][j]=10;

for row in grid:
    print(row)
```